# SharePoint Slide Library linking

Tags: powerpoint, slidelibrary

I have one slide in several different Slide libraries on Sharepoint 2010, and currently have to manually update each slide in each slide library. Is there a way that I can link my slide in 3 different Slide Libraries together so that I only have to update one slide and it updates in all the different libraries?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way to share a slide to multiple slide libraries so that you only have to update one slide, but you will then have to force the update to the slides in the other libraries.
1) Navigate to the slide library containing the slide you want to share; this will become the "master" slide and all updates wil have to be done to this slide.
2) Hover over the slide name, click the down arrow, and select Send To > Other Location. 
3) Enter the URL for the destination library, a file name for the copy, and whether to prompt the author to send out updates when the document is checked out.
4) You will receive a prompt that you are about to copy the item to another location; select OK.
5) You will then receive a message that the operation was successful; select Done.
6) Repeat the process to send to any additional libraries.
When you click on the down arrow on the "master" and select Send To, you will see that a new menu item is available: Existing Copies. When you update this slide, select this option to update all other copies of the slide; you will be prompted to select which versions of the slide you would like to update.